# how to run a python pygame file on a django website (without using path)?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pygame, python-requests

I am making a website with `Django`.

I created a python file and I'd like to run that file on my website. How to do that?

```py
import requests
import pygame,sys

pygame.init()

//code 

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: @Stevy given the script that he wants to execute, I wouldn't consider this a duplicate.  Also, the question you linked is a terrible question...

Comment: You are right. I did not realise it was a pygame file. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: can someone please answer my question

Comment: Your browser cannot run python, so basically you cannot run a pygame inside the browser. You would need a javascript wrapper that sends events (user input) to your back-end in a format that needs to be translated to pygame events, and in return receives the screen updates live (via a web socket). I don't know if such wrapper exists but in general, running games over the network is not an easy task (due to latency). So to put it simply: the answer is it's not possible.